# Why coarse maps have to be proper?

Tags: metric-spaces, uniform-continuity, geometric-group-theory, uniform-spaces

A map $f: X \to Y$ between metric spaces is said to be ***coarse***, if the following two conditions hold:

1. $f$ is bornologous, i.e. 
   $$\forall_{R>0} \; \exists_{S>0} \; d(x,y) < R \Rightarrow d(f(x),f(y)) < S $$
2. $f$ is (metrically) proper, i.e. preimages of bounded sets are bounded

My question is, why do we need the "2." condition in this definition? **Why coarse maps have to be proper?**

Some background:

Coarse map is a basic concept of coarse geometry and this definition is given in the book *Lectures on Coarse Geometry* by John Roe, one of the founding fathers of the subject.  I don't know who formulated this definition first, but all references that I've seen point there.

As I understand, the central notion of interest here are *coarse equivalences*, which are the isomorhpisms in the coarse category, which are those maps that have *coarse inverses*: for coarse map $f$ there must be a coarse map $g:Y\to X$ such that $g\circ f$ and $f\circ g$ are bornotopic to the identity, i.e. $$ \sup_{x\in X}\; d( \ g(f(x)) , \ x) < \infty \qquad \sup_{y\in Y}\; d( \ f(g(y)) , \ y) < \infty$$

This gives intuitive results like $\mathbb{Z}$ being coarsely equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$ - which we imagine as looking at $\mathbb{Z}$ from far away, when line of discrete points merge to continuous line. Or that the Cayley diagram of a group $\pi_1(X)$ is coarsely equivalent to the universal cover of $X$ - no matter what presentation of $\pi_1(X)$ we use. In fact, coarse maps have great applications in geometric group theory and I suspect the answer may be hidden there.

But if we exclude properness from the definition, then if $f$ is a coarse equivalence, then it is proper. So removing this property does not add any new coarse equivalences. I don't see other reasons why properness should stay.

If we look at a close cousin of coarse spaces, namely uniform spaces (indeed we can look at bornologous/coarse maps as "uniformly bounded" maps), we see that an uniform map is just a uniformly continuous map, i.e. satisfying $$\forall_{\varepsilon > 0} \; \exists_{\delta>0} \; d(x,y)<\delta \Rightarrow d(f(x),f(y)) < \varepsilon $$ while it doesn't have any proper-like condition. (Would it be something along the lines - "images of small sets are small"? Maybe it already holds?)

Moreover, if we consider the product of two metric spaces $X\times Y$, then the usual projection maps $\pi_X,\pi_Y$ are **not** coarse, so they don't form a product in the coarse category. This is really nonappealing for me. So I suppose there must be a good reason to do this.

From the terminology, I can expect that equating the concepts of *coarse* and *bornologous* maps is not really fruitful, but I want to see the reason why.

Edit: I found a paper[1] which defines the $\mathbf{Coarse}$ category with bornological maps, not coarse maps. (It keep the names the same, though.)
I suppose naming categories is just a convention, but nevertheless *coarse map* is still a thing, so my question still holds.

[1] Some categorical aspects of coarse spaces and balleans; D.Dikranjan, N.Zava

Comment: Properness is very natural if you consider the setting of finitely generated subgroups of finitely generated groups: The inclusion $H < G$ is a proper map.

Comment: I don't see why that is anticipated. On the other hand, the projection G×G -> G is not (usually) proper. Examples don't help me here. What I would want to see, is some theorems that work only if the map is coarse (so they need both bornology and properness). For example, for continuous maps we have intermediate value theorem, which illustrates what *continuous* is all about.

Comment: A homomorphism between finitely generated groups is proper if and only if it has finite kernel. Try to prove this.

Comment: I can prove it. Sadly, I don't see any intuition about coarse maps steaming from it.

Comment: Do you have an intuition for what restricting to bornologous maps would get you? What sort of questions you would answer? Would they be geometric or maybe more analysis or something else? What does having products get you? In your mind what should a coarse category be? What sort of questions should it help answer? Does having the arrows be bornology answer these questions? Even whether or not a coarse map exists between two different spaces is an interesting invariant (between the euclidean plane and hyperbolic plane).

Comment: If "bornology maps are not very geometric" isn't a good answer to you I think you need to add more what you are looking for in an answer or your current understanding of why you don't find that good enough or what you expect from a coarse category. Answering some of the above question might be able to get someone to give you a satisfactory answer. At the moment you just seem annoyed about the name(you can call them proper bornologies if you want) or just really want products for no apparent reason and you have given no indication for why that would be desirable.

Comment: Rereading your question maybe the problem is you think coarse equivalence is the key interest, and that bornology equivalence gives you the same answers? Certainly that can be interesting but I think the key is more about invariants/being able to tell things apart(and when they are the same). Does that help make it make more sense?

Comment: "Bornology maps are not very geometric" is a good answer, but still arcane to me. I really appreciate the snake map example though, it shines at least some light on the issue.
Are you saying that there are some invariants that coarse maps respect, that bornology maps don't? I would like to see more of those so I could guide my intuition. My intuition now is that bornology maps already respect the coarse structure, like continuous maps or uniform maps - so adding second condition seems unintuitive for me and I wanted to understand reasons behind it.

Comment: The paper I mentioned in my edit states, that the category with coarse spaces as objects and bornology maps as morphisms is [topological](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category). Frankly I don't really understand the term now, but I see it has many consequences that would come for free and is somewhat elegant.

Comment: There are also other papers that define the coarse category without using the "proper" requirement. See for example Eric Guentner paper on permanence in coarse geometry: http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~erik/papers/permanence.pdf

Comment: Also, from a purely philosophical point, you probably want coarse map to preserve at least some "large-scale structure," the same way that continuous maps copreserve "small-scale structure." However, if you define a coarse map as a map satisfying only the first condition, then any constant map is coarse. This seems intuitively wrong from the large-scale point of view.

Answer (score 4):

The main point is that I don't really think bornologous maps are really geometric generally. Consider a surjective map on the real numbers which snakes/bounces back and forth going further each time. This does not seem like it should be a coarse maps but it bornologous if you snake back and forth at a constant rate. It isn't metrically proper though since the preimage of 0 will be unbounded. If you are trying to do geometry you probably don't want to deal with maps like.

One thing you mention is that your understanding is that being coarsely equivalent and "bornology equivalence" give the same equivalences and that you think this is the main point of interest. Certainly that equivalence is interesting but it is not necessarily the point, you want interesting invariants. Even whether or not coarse maps exist between different spaces is interesting. For example consider the spaces: regular 4-valent tree(standard Cayley graph of free group on two generators), hyperbolic 2-space, hyperbolic 3-space, Euclidean 2-space, and Eulcidean 3-space. What are the bornologous maps between pairs of these spaces(there are tons)? What are the coarse maps between spaces? Are there any? I think that by thinking about this you will realize that existence of coarse maps(and non existence) actually tell you something about the spaces geometry.

Related to the above is [asymptotic dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_dimension), which coarse maps play nicely with. If you have a coarse map $X \to Y$ then $\operatorname{asdim} X \leq \operatorname{asdim} Y$. The same is not true at all for bornologous maps. A particularly important theorem along these lines is that if a finitely generated group has finite asymptotic dimension then it satisfies the [Novikov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_conjecture) conjeture(a big open problem in topology having to do with whether or not something is invariant under homotopy).

In geometry one is often interested in boundaries and/or compactifications of a space $X$, and particularly how these interact with maps. Now under some constraints(see *Lectures on Coarse Geometry* by Roe) you can get coarse maps 
$X \to Y$ 
extend to maps on the boundary. I am not to familiar with Higson corona and Higson compactification but these are in some sense universal boundaries which you would be interested in. Certainly bornologous maps do not in general extend to maps on boundaries.

I am not familiar with the theory but there is a theory of coarse cohomology, and this is a (contravariant)functor on coarse maps.

I haven't really worked in the generality of coarse structure(not necessarily just looking at metric spaces) but another reason is it has to do with that definition, which intuitively is where you define all your negligible sets, and for metric spaces it is natural that negligible sets are the bounded ones. Just like in topology, or uniform continuity, preimage of open is open and it is natural to say preimage of negligible is negligible. From this perspective you might even consider bornology to be the added on condition in order to add uniformity.

What is added by having projections coarse maps or products in the coarse category? You can still have metric products, but I don't really see what is of interest in making sure that projections are coarse maps.

---

Coarse maps is not the end all be all of coarse geometry though, there are interesting maps which are not proper, and geometric information can be pulled from them. For example to study mapping class groups of surfaces Masur and Minsky developed a theory of "hierarchies" where geometry of the mapping class group is studied by looking at (not proper) projections to something called curve graphs of subsurfaces.

Comment: Or you can instead talk about the bornology category

Comment: If projections were coarse, $(X\times Y,\pi_X ,\pi_Y )$ would be a product in coarse category. Currently it isn't. I want coarse category to have products.

Comment: @mzg147 Is there a reason you want products other than you just want them? Not all categories have products(fields don't have products for example). If you want to just work with bornology do that but if you are interested in geometry/coarse geometry bornology collapse and don't necessarily have much to do with geometry. There are lots of bornologous maps so you won't be able to make statements like there is no coarse map from hyperbolic space to hyperbolic plane. Also the coarse category is more general than just metric spaces.

Comment: I just say then there must be a good reason why we take this definition. I understand why fields are what they are. But I don't know **why** the snake map that you mentioned in your answer **shouldn't** be coarse. Why bornology don't have to do with geometry but coarseness do?

Comment: Could you also explain what properness give us when studying asymptotic dimension?

Comment: @mzg147 Do you think the snake map tells you something about the geometry of either space other than unboundedness? If $X \to Y$ is coarse then the asymptotic dimension of $Y$ is greater or equal to $X$'s. In geometric group theory maps are quasi-isometry, or quasi-isometric embedding because just coarse Lipschitz map just don't really say much about geometry (without more restrictions). Also, coarse maps isn't the end all be all of coarse geometry, there does end up being coarse geometry without it(for example Masur-Minsky hierarchies), but not really when the only restriction in bornologous.

Comment: Perhaps someone who knows more about coarse topology can comment or answer, but my understanding is that coarse maps are also the correct maps to deal with when dealing with things like coarse cohomology theories

Comment: The criterion that if there exists coarse $f: X -> Y$ then $\dim X \leq \dim Y$ is a example I am looking for. Could you edit this in your last paragraph?

Comment: Added a bit more @mzg147

Comment: Do you have a reference to the claim that when $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a coarse map, then $asdim(X) \leq asdim(Y)$? I always thought that the map had to be also effectively proper and not just coarse.